# Need to put an ajax confirmation box instead of page for delete in zend framework using ajax

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

This is the code which i am currently using and not able to understand how to insert ajax code

I have read many more posts on this website but i am still unable to understand how is that i insert the code for ajax

```
<?php

class FacController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');
        if ($del == 'Yes') {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
        $details = new Application_Model_DbTable_Details();
        $details->deleteDetails($id);
        }
        $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
        $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
        $details = new Application_Model_DbTable_Details();
        $this->view->details = $details->getDetails($id);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that your index action displays a list of something that you want deleted.

The way you do deleting via ajax is quite simple.

1. Write a delete action, that returns the deletion status
2. Call it via ajax, and do the appropriate response.

Now how this would all look like:

### index.phtml

This view should contain something like the following code for jQuery:

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
    var menuId = $("ul.nav").first().attr("id");
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "/index/delete",
      type: "POST",
      data: {id : menuId},
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
      $("#log").html( msg );
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
});
```

### IndexController:deleteAction()

```
public function deleteAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout(); //This disables the layout
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE); //This disables need for delete.phtml
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
        $details = new Application_Model_DbTable_Details();
        $status=$details->deleteDetails($id); //Lets add a status check to know if we have successfully deleted something
        if($status){
            echo json_encode(true);
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode(false);
        }
    }
```

Even though I have not extensively tested this code, this should put you on the right track.